# How to send audio API HIKVISION for two-way-audio?

Tags: camera

I need help to understand why when sending audio to the camera you hear ugly, very fast.
The camera is configured audio codec G711Ulaw

The process I am doing is the following:

- I download a wav audio and converted to the codec that the camera is configured, these are all evidence conversions.

  ```
  ffmpeg -i padrino.wav -acodec pcm_mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 -b:a 32k output.wav  
  ffmpeg -i padrino.wav -acodec pcm_mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 2 -b:a 32000 output.wav  
  ffmpeg -i padrino.wav -f mulaw -acodec pcm_mulaw -ac 1 output.wav  
  ffmpeg -i padrino.wav -ar 8000 -ac 1 -ab 64k -f mulaw output.ulaw
  ```
- Turned on the two-way-audio, within the "data.xml" is the xml that enables two-way-audio:

  ```
  curl -H "application/xml" -X PUT -d @data.xml USER:PASS@IPCAM/ISAPI/System/...hannels/1/open
  ```
- I send through a curl

  ```
  curl -H "application/binary" -X PUT -d @output.ulaw USER:PASS@IPCAM/ISAPI/System/...ls/1/audioData
  ```

  or

  ```
  curl -H "application/binary" -X PUT -d @output.wav USER:PASS@IPCAM/ISAPI/System/...ls/1/audioData
  ```

This is heard in camera but as I explained at the beginning is heard wrong, I distorted, very fast.
What am I doing wrong?

regards

Comment: Did you ever get this working, I have been testing here and I just hear a click when I send the audio data.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out why this is - its nothing to do with the encoding. I have written a C# app to test this and if you send the data at the rate expected (8000 samples per second) then it plays correctly.

I send the audio data in packets (160 bytes currently but experimenting with optimum values but does not seem to matter much as long as the delay is correct) and delay for the appropriate amount of time before sending again so that the correct amount of samples are sent in a second.

Comment: Did you ever get this working without C# code? - e.g. with javascript or curl or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/electric-monk/mqtt-hikvision/blob/master/hiksound.py) interesting a project on github that helped me create this simple app that can send the audio to the camera using python:

```py
import urllib.request
import requests
import socket
import time


class SocketGrabber:
    """ A horrible hack, so as to allow us to recover
        the socket we still need from urllib """

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self._temp = socket.socket.close
        socket.socket.close = lambda sock: self._close(sock)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        socket.socket.close = self._temp
        if tb is not None:
            self.sock = None

    def _close(self, sock):
        if sock._closed:
            return
        if self.sock == sock:
            return
        if self.sock is not None:
            self._temp(self.sock)
        self.sock = sock


audio_file = "output.ulaw"
ip = "IPCAM"
username = "USER"
password = "PASS"
index = 1
base = f"http://{ip}"
chunksize = 128
sleep_time = 1.0 / 64

base_url = f"http://{username}:{password}@{ip}"
req = requests.put(
    f"{base_url}/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/{index}/open")

mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
mgr.add_password(None, [base], username, password)
auth = urllib.request.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth)
audiopath = f"{base}/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/{index}/audioData"

with SocketGrabber() as sockgrab:
    req = urllib.request.Request(audiopath, method='PUT')
    resp = opener.open(req)
    output = sockgrab.sock


def frames_yield(ulaw_data, chunksize=128):
    for i in range(0, len(ulaw_data), chunksize):
        for x in [ulaw_data[i:i + chunksize]]:
            tosend = x + (b'\xff' * (chunksize - len(x)))
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            yield tosend


with open(audio_file, 'rb') as file_obj:
    ulaw_data = file_obj.read()
    for dataframe in frames_yield(ulaw_data, chunksize):
        output.send(dataframe)
```